# Is raw gps coordinate on android mobile devices already improved with Kalman

Tags: android, localization, gps, kalman-filter

I am working on an application for navigation on android. That basically means that quality of returned gps coordinate is crucial for me. The application is meant to be mostly used on Samsung Galaxy S3, with minimum SDK version 15.
I have thought of using Kalman filter to improve my location data, however I am not quite sure if this can bring me some progress. I have heard that gps data on android devices is already preprocessed with Kalman by I am not quite sure if this is true.
So if somebody knows it would be very important for me to know if return coordinate from location sensor is already preprocessed with Kalman and also if the answer is yes, about the state description used in Kalman filter, that is which other sensors are used to describe state of the system.

Thank you in advance for your answer.

Answer (score 0):

Gps chips deliver positions already Kalmann filtered, otherwise they would be unusable.
And of course the details of the Kalman implementation is secret.